# Embedding Jython in a scala program

Tags: scala, jython

I'd like to embed the Jython interpreter in a Scala program.  I'm having trouble getting the script engine, however.

I'm using SBT v0.13.15.  Here's my build.sbt file:

```
name := "jython"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.python" % "jython" % "2.7.0",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
)
```

My Scala code is

```
package forms

import javax.script._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager()
    for (i ← 0 until engineManager.getEngineFactories.size()) {
      val e = engineManager.getEngineFactories.get(i)
      println(s"factory name: ${e.getEngineName}, ${e.getLanguageName}, ${e.getNames}")
    }

    val engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("python")
    require(engine != null, "Script engine is null.")
  }
}
```

This outputs

```
factory name: Scala Interpreter, Scala, [scala]
factory name: Oracle Nashorn, ECMAScript, [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]
factory name: jython, python, [python, jython]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Script engine is null.
```

So it appears that the engine manager knows about the python factory but is unable to "get" it or instantiate it.  I've tried accessing it with the name "python" and "jython" with similar results.

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168226/sbt-0-13-scriptengine-is-null-for-getenginebyname-javascript) that passing null to ScriptEngineManager helps, but for me that was a step backwards.  It only found the nashorn factory.

I've also tried instantiating the python factory directly:

```
val engine = (new PyScriptEngineFactory).getScriptEngine
```

But this produces an error that looks like progress is being made but I don't know how to resolve:

```
Exception in thread "main" ImportError: Cannot import site module and its dependencies: No module named site
Determine if the following attributes are correct:
  * sys.path: ['/Users/bwbecker/.ivy2/cache/org.python/jython/jars/Lib', '__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/']
    This attribute might be including the wrong directories, such as from CPython
  * sys.prefix: /Users/bwbecker/.ivy2/cache/org.python/jython/jars
    This attribute is set by the system property python.home, although it can
    be often automatically determined by the location of the Jython jar file
```

I speculate that the two approaches may have the same fundamental problem.  The first approach simply catches the initialization error and returns null.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the attempt to import the site module by placing the following code before the call to get the engine (either using the EngineManager or directly with PyScriptEngineFactory):

```
import org.python.core.Py
import org.python.core.PySystemState

val props = new Properties()
props.setProperty("python.import.site", "false")
PySystemState.initialize(props, new Properties())
val engineSys = new PySystemState
Py.setSystemState(engineSys)
```